# How to create a child branch?

Tags: git, github

I have created a child branch of master branch. and i'm confused that is it a right way or not.

```
command : git checkout -b master-website-delete-parent-menu-ras odoo/master
```

and it is also showing some messege

```
Branch 'master-website-delete-parent-menu-ras' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 
'odoo'.
Switched to a new branch 'master-website-delete-parent-menu-ras'
```

Comment: Depending on your workflow, you might want to check that the branch actually has to have `master` as its pull/push source/destination, which *is* the case here. If you wanted to have a remote version of the branch, to be able to do pull requests to `master`, consider resetting its upstream with `git push -u odoo master-website-delete-parent-menu-ras`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
git checkout -b branch2 origin/master
```

This means:

- Create a new branch `branch2`, from `origin/master`.
- But also, set `origin/master` as the tracked branch of `branch2`. So `git push` will push to `origin/master`.

This is a bit unconventional but it could work. But I think you're looking the *feature branch workflow*:

### Feature branch workflow

With this workflow, you will create for every feature (bugfixes are also features here) a new branch, from the branch master.

#### Setup

First of all, it's recommend to set the push default:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

This will makes push easier as there is no need to specify where to push to. (branch X will push to origin/X - see below)

### Create branch

How to create a `branch2` from `master`:

```
git checkout master # switch to master
git pull master # update local master
git checkout -b branch2 # create new branch from current branch
```

### Push branch

And when done with all you commits, you could push it like this:

```
git push -u
```

The `-u` is only needed for the first push of this new branch. This will set the tracking branch to origin/branch2 (because of `push.default current`).

Note: there are many other ways in git commands to create and push branch. I think this a good approach, but feel free to use other commands.

More to read about [Gitflow workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow)

Hope this helps!